# iOS Shortcut to get values into calculator

Tags: ios, applet, shortcut, ios-shortcut

To long a long story short I am trying to create a iOS shortcut and display it in the calculator.

I got the dictate working right and then I have my number being display in a alert but I dont know how I can get the number into the calculator!

Comment: What have you tried already? Please [edit] your question and add a [example]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be an “open in calculator” action at the moment. However what you can do is use the “copy to clipboard” action on the number you want. Use the “open app” action. And press on the number and select paste

Not the best option, but hopefully it should get you to what you want!